# How to add condition to value_counts method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe named concatenated_df

[image]

I am plotting the data with the following code

```
(concatenated_df[concatenated_df.DAY.eq('Tuesday')].groupby('COMPANY')['STATUS'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack().plot.bar())
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

which gives me an output plot as

[image]

How can I plot only those values which are greater than 0.8?
In the current example, it should print only VEDL.NS and WIPRO.NS

Comment: btw  I didn't downvote but you I think that you got downvoted bcz you didn't provided [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also have a look on [why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20can't%20be%20searched,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.)

Answer (score 0):

you can filter Data frame which has values greater than 80 and save it into new data frame and then plot it

you can use this for example
but you need to sepcify wich colum are you want to fillter

```
new_df= df[df.b > 80]
plot df2
```

Comment: That cannot be done as these values are coming from value_counts(normalize=True)